# How to set an ArrayAdapter to a String Array using the resource id (R.string.)

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

1. I tried to cast the returned value from the resource into a string but it doesn't work.
2. this is my code:

   ```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        String[] storiesTitles = {(String) getText(R.string.first_story_title), (String) getText(R.string.second_story_title), (String) getText(R.string.third_story_title)};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, storiesTitles);

            ListView list = findViewById(R.id.lv_stories);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link:
[Android documentation: string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

And this is the solution you are looking for:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

The 'planets' array will contains all the string you defined for it in the strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Call the string array inside onCreate function

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   
 String[] storiesTitles = {(String) getText(R.string.first_story_title), (String) getText(R.string.second_story_title), (String) getText(R.string.third_story_title)};

             ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, storiesTitles);
    
             ListView list = findViewById(R.id.lv_stories);
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
    
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably get this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myniprojects.testsave/com.myniprojects.testsave.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

You have to init array in `onCreate` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] storiesTitles = {(String) getText(R.string.first_story_title), (String) getText(R.string.second_story_title), (String) getText(
                R.string.third_story_title)};

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                                                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                                                storiesTitles
        );

        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.lv_stories);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Now it should work. But easier way is to make this like that:

in `res/values/strings.xml` add:

```
<string-array name="titles_array">
    <item>First title</item>
    <item>Second title</item>
    <item>Third title</item>
</string-array>
```

And MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] storiesTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles_array);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
                                                          android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                                                          storiesTitles
        );

        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.lv_stories);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the two methods don't work and when i run the code it popup a window says (app name) has stopped.

Comment: So the problem must be somewhere else. You have to add logcat so someone can help You. `app name has stopped` says nothing. It can be everything